# call function from child class in parent class?

Tags: android

I want to use my function "list" from child class(menu) in parent class(Main1Activity) how can I do this so that I will use that function to call my list?

And I don't want to make function in parent class

```
public class Main1Activity extends Activity{
    // i want to use list function here 
}

public class menu extends Main1Activity {
   public void list(View view) {
       //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked", 3000).show();
       Cursor cursor2=mydb1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM notes;", null);

       if  (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
           //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title's are:", 3000).show();
           data.clear();

           do {
               data.add(cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex("title"))); 
           } while (cursor2.moveToNext());

           ArrayAdapter <String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);

           lv.setAdapter(adapter);
       }
       else {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are no notes to display ", 3000).show();
       }
       cursor2.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: **"And I don't want to make function in parent class"** - It can't be done. A super class can never know about sub-classes. Through inheritance your menu class is a Main1Activity class but Main1Activity is not a menu class. I would suggest you study OOP in more depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not notice the inheritance between your classes but this is still an option.

Put in separate class.

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void list(Context context, View view)
}

public class Main1Activity extends Activity{
    // i want to use list function here 
    SomeClass.list(this, view);
}

public class menu extends Main1Activity {
    SomeClass.list(this, view);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is not well thinking at all. You should review the way you proceed, considering abstract class and interface.

You should explain why you want to do this, it might help.